# Problem with respawned camera in Unity3D in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with camera in Unity. I want to follow to the ball. I want to make auto respawn for the ball and camera. But the code works but camera doesn't follow to the ball.
This is code for auto respawn:

```
public class start : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject Camera;
public GameObject Ball;
void Start()
{
    GameObject ball = GameObject.Instantiate(Ball);
    Ball.name = "Ball";
    ball.transform.position = transform.position + Vector3.up * 0.5f;
    Instantiate(Camera);
    Camera.name = "Camera";
    Camera.transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0.25f, 1.75f, 6.5f);
}
```

The code for camera controller:

```
public Transform Ball;
void Update()
{
    Rigidbody rigidbody = Ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    float ballVelocity = rigidbody.velocity.sqrMagnitude;

    UnityEngine.Vector3 vector = new UnityEngine.Vector3(0, 4, 7);
    vector *= (1+ ballVelocity / 30);
    UnityEngine.Vector3 nowaPozycjaKamery = Ball.position + vector;
    transform.position = UnityEngine.Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, nowaPozycjaKamery, Time.deltaTime*5);
    transform.LookAt(Ball);
}
```

Camera worked well before auto respawn. Code work that on start camera follow to good position, but is freezed when the ball change the position.

Comment: Is it possible that you respawn the ball after the camera?
If so, the camera follows the old ball item

Comment: when you did `Camera.GetComponent<CameraController>();` which alone makes no sense did you mabye mean `Camera.GetComponent<CameraController>().Ball = ball.transform;` ?

Comment: No because old ball doesn't exist.

Comment: I have an error If i do that. I can delete it 

Answer (score 0):

I wish you provided more information on this question. Like is there any NullReferenceException or other exceptions. But I'll try to answer your issue anyways. I think the problem is that the camera script doesn't have the reference to the new ball that's being spawned (this is in the case of destroying the old ball and Instantiating a new one with [Destroy(gameObject)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)).

What I suggest is to add a Method in the camera script that will be in charge of injecting the new ball into the script. And then you call this method with the new spawned ball in the script responsible for spawning. Or a more straightforward but not efficient way is to check if the ball property is null and then you make a call to [GameObject.Find("Name of The ball object")](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) and you give the name of the ball object.